# How to use Let's Encrypt free SSL on Namecheap shared hosting?

Tags: openssl, namecheap

There is no tutorial on Google about how to install free Let's Encrypt SSL on Namecheap shared hosting. I need to install SSL certificate on my website.

Comment: Questions here should be specific in scope - tutorials are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: https://youtu.be/TFM8hECnIPY

Answer (score 1):

> In general Let's Encrypt will often require some level of support from
>   a shared hosting provider, and we hope to talk to many of the hosting
>   providers to make sure that they take whatever steps are necessary to
>   achieve that support. There may be some configurations in which
>   hosting providers already allow users to deploy certs without the
>   providers' intervention; in those configurations it may be possible
>   for a shared hosting user to get a Let's Encrypt cert and install it
>   manually.
>
> It will almost always require the provider's assistance to allow the
>   process to be automated on the provider's infrastructure (for example,
>   installing the cert automatically or renewing the cert automatically).

Found at https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/shared-hosting/384 via a google search for `install letsencrypt on shared hosting`

Comment: I have already contacted with them. They're saying that "Let's Encrypt is a third party company. We cannot help you with installing Let's Encrypt free SSL. But it is possible to install Let's Encrypt SSL on Namecheap shared hosting".

Comment: Find a new hosting company that is easier to work with.  Likely this one is still trying to sell SSL certificates and doesn't like that they are now available for free

Comment: https://www.deltadigit.com/install-lets-encrypt-namecheap-shared-hosting/

Comment: https://youtu.be/TFM8hECnIPY